# How to disable a button click on pageload in JS?

Tags: javascript, button

I have a HTML code present in the **DOM** as shown below. The following HTML code displays on page-load:

```
<td style="width:5%; text-align:center;"><button style="text-align:center; width:120px;" data-id="0"  class="converter btn btn-outline-primary"> Completed                  </button></td>

<td style="width:5%; text-align:center;"><button style="text-align:center; width:120px;" data-id="1"  class="converter btn btn-outline-primary"> Completed                  </button></td>
```

When the text is **Completed** in button tag, I want the click to be disable on button.

This is what I have tried :

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("converter");

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('converter').innerText[i] == "Completed") {     // Line A
        document.getElementsByClassName('converter').disabled = true;
    }
}
```

I am getting error at **Line A**:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May something like this?

```js
var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".converter"); // use querySelectorAll(".className") 
elements.forEach(function(element) { // elements is an array you need to iterate over it
    console.log(element.innerText);  // just to log and see something if it works ...
    if("Completed" === element.innerText) { // this is the test
        element.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled'); // set the attribute
    }
});
```

```html
<td style="width:5%; text-align:center;"><button style="text-align:center; width:120px;" data-id="0"  class="converter btn btn-outline-primary"> Completed                  </button></td>

<td style="width:5%; text-align:center;"><button style="text-align:center; width:120px;" data-id="1"  class="converter btn btn-outline-primary"> Completed                  </button></td>
```

[Read more about document.querySelectorAll() and how to use it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: it worked, thanks for the help. I am wondering, let say if I want to background-color: green around the button. Should I have to do something like this  ? `element.style.background-color = "green";`

Comment: @john it's `document.body.style.background = 'green';` also consider google first something like "javascript set background color" and you will get 1'000'000 useful results

Answer (score 0):

**getElementsByClassName()** returns an HTMLcollection object , so the for loop should be as below

1. Looping x will return each element with converter class by using **x[i]**
2. `x[i].innerText` and `x[i].disabled` will work as expected from your code but not document.getElementsByClassName('converter').innerText[i] which is invalid and throws error
3. Change backgroundColor using **x[i].style.backgroundColor**

   x[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";

Please refer this link for more details on getElementsByClassName-  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("converter");

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].innerText == "Completed") {     // Line A
        x[i].disabled = true;
        x[i].style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
}
```

```html
<table><tr>
  <td style="width:5%; text-align:center;"><button style="text-align:center; width:120px;" data-id="0"  class="converter btn btn-outline-primary"> Completed                  </button></td>

<td style="width:5%; text-align:center;"><button style="text-align:center; width:120px;" data-id="1"  class="converter btn btn-outline-primary"> Completed                  </button></td>
  </tr></table>
```

Comment: @john, updated code to change style, style property names should be camel case - fontSize, backgroundColor -  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style

Answer (score 0):

same code, Juste change **.innerText[i]** to **[i].innerText.trim()** like this:

```js
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('converter');
 
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('converter')[i].innerHTML.trim() == "Completed") {     // Line A
        document.getElementsByClassName('converter')[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
```

```html
<td style="width:5%; text-align:center;"><button style="text-align:center; width:120px;" data-id="0"  class="converter btn btn-outline-primary"> Completed                  </button></td>

<td style="width:5%; text-align:center;"><button style="text-align:center; width:120px;" data-id="1"  class="converter btn btn-outline-primary"> Completed                  </button></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the innerText of the elem at i index of `document.getElementsByClassName('converter')`
and to do that you can use `document.getElementsByClassName('converter')[i].innerText = "whatever"`

Also since you already declared the variable x for `document.getElementsByClassName('converter')` why not use it?

(Correct code would be)

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("converter");

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (x[i].innerText == "Completed") {//Line A
        x[i].disabled = true;
    }
}
```

Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until the elements are loaded in DOM before iterate over them, otherwise they would be `undefined`.
To do that listen to the "DOMContentLoaded" document event and then iterate.

Check for:
[DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event) and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
  // Here we have shure that the elements exists.
  
  // Get all the elements you need.
  var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".converter");
  
  // Iterate and set the value you need.
  elements.forEach(function(el) {
    if(el.innerText === "Completed") {
      el.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
      el.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<td style="width:5%; text-align:center;"><button style="text-align:center; width:120px;" data-id="0" class="converter btn btn-outline-primary">Completed</button></td>
<td style="width:5%; text-align:center;"><button style="text-align:center; width:120px;" data-id="1" class="converter btn btn-outline-primary">Completed</button></td>
```